# Return Zero If Item Within Array Loop Is Not Available And Arrange Items As Week Days

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this array:

```
"Month" => array:4 [    
    "Week 1" => array:1 [
        "Monday"    => 1
    ]
    "Week 2" => array:3 [
        "Tuesday"   => 69
        "Wednesday" => 17
        "Friday"    => 3
    ]
    "Week 3" => array:1 [
        "Thursday"  => 3
    ]
    "Week 4" => array:2 [
        "Monday"    => 15
        "Friday"    => 24
    ]
]
```

But I need to display the result as follow:

```
| Week   | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
|--------|--------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|
| Week 1 | 1      | 0       | 0         | 0        | 0      |
| Week 2 | 0      | 69      | 17        | 0        | 3      |
| Week 3 | 0      | 0       | 0         | 3        | 0      |
| Week 4 | 15     | 0       | 0         | 0        | 24     |
```

I have tried the following but it's showing results for more than 5 days in each week

```
<table>
<tr>

foreach ($weeks as $key => $weekcount)
{

if($key == "Monday"){ <td><?php $weekcount ?></td> }
elseif($key == "Tuesday"){ <td><?php $weekcount ?></td> } 
elseif($key == "Wednesday"){ <td><?php $weekcount ?></td> }
elseif($key == "Thursday"){ <td><?php $weekcount ?></td>} 
elseif($key == "Friday"){ <td><?php $weekcount ?></td> }
else {<td><?php $weekcount ?></td>}

}

</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable contributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the given day (key) exists in the array if it is not you should write 0 to the table.

Here is a sample code:

```php
<?php

$data = [

    'Month' =>  [

        'Week1' => [
            'Monday' => 1
        ],

        'Week2' => [
            'Tuesday'   => 69,
            'Wednesday' => 17,
            'Friday'    => 3
        ],

        'Week3' => [
            'Thursday' => 3
        ],

        'Week4' => [
            'Monday' => 15,
            'Friday' => 24
        ]
    ]

];

$weeks = $data['Month'];

?>

<table>

<tr>
    <th>Week</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
</tr>

<?php
$days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];
?>

<?php foreach ($weeks as $key => $week) { ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
        <?php foreach ($days as $day) { ?>

        <td><?php if (array_key_exists($day, $week)) { echo $week[$day]; } else { echo '0'; } ?></td>

        <?php } ?>
    <tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 2):

Hope It will help !

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>

      <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
      $data = [
          "week 1" => [
            "Monday" => 1
          ],
          "week 2" => [
            "Tuesday" => 69,
            "Wednesday" => 17,
            "Friday" => 3
          ],
          "week 3" => [
            "Thursday" => 3
          ],
          "week 4" => [
            "Monday" => 15,
            "Friday" => 24
          ]
        ];
        $array1 = ['Monday', 'Tuesday' , 'Wednesday' , 'Thursday' , 'Friday'];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        ?>  
           <tr>
                <td><?php echo $key ?></td>
                <?php 
                  foreach ($array1 as $arr) {
                    if(!array_key_exists($arr, $value)){
                      $value[$arr] = 0;
                    } 
                ?>
                <td><?php echo  $value[$arr] ?></td>

              <?php } ?>

            </tr>
       <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```